# Inline in aspx, stripping date off of datetime

Tags: asp.net

I think if I just show you the following what I'm asking will make sense.

In a link in my aspx, this works:
    ' title='<%# Container.DataItem["EventTime"].ToString()

But the above contains the date portion of the string.

This does not work (nor does any variant of it):
    ' title='<%# Container.DataItem["EventTime"].ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>

Evantually, we want the title/hover for the link to read something like  "4:30 PM : @Forbes Field"

Everything is working with the exception of the 1/1/1900 being in front of the 4:30

How do I get the date off that EventTime datetime field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataItem` indexer returns an `object` reference, so you can't use `DateTime` specific methods without casting it. You can also use the `String.Format` method:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", Container.DataItem["EventTime"]) %>
```

Comment: SWEET!! That worked beautifully, Guffa.  Thank you 1) for the rapid response, and 2) for a response that completely solved the issue.